# Finding green investment funds

Tags: mutual-funds, pension

I'm trying to find green/sustainable funds to add to my (UK) pension and am finding it quite hard to pick out good candidates. I'm interested more in the green credentials than in the performance.

Ideally I'd be looking for funds which invest in things like carbon capture, heat pump technology, wind and solar of course (that is relatively easy to find) and also water treatment/distribution.

The wind and solar sides are not too hard to find, in fact I already have investments in funds and individual companies. Anything else seems to be maybe too niche?

A lot of the general sustainable/green funds sound good, but when you look into their actual investments, a lot are in technology in general i.e. Microsoft, Adobe etc. Whilst I've nothing against those companies, that's not my focus for this purpose. I already have as much as I want invested in that sector, my purpose in investing in green tech. is not to help sell more copies of Photoshop!

Any ideas?

Comment: Carbon-capture is hard to find except that major European oil companies are interested in carbon-capture and interested in making synthetic fuel from carbon-dioxide. Or Air Products is involved in hydrogen production where carbon-dioxide is captured and that's "blue hydrogen".